# Dropdown Menu Mouseleave Event Should Ignore Child Elements

Tags: javascript

I was fooling around and trying to build the same dropdown menu as Google uses on this page: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation

I have an issue where the drop menu closes when the mouse leaves the parent nav element for the dropdown menu. What can I do to improve this? Item 3 in my example contains the dropdown menu. This is just a practice snippet. I'm in no rush to complete it.

```js
(function() {
 const parentNav = document.querySelector('.parent-nav');
 const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');

 parentNav.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
  menuTransition();
  this.classList.add('dropdown-open');
 });

 parentNav.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
  menuTransition();
  this.classList.remove('dropdown-open');
 });

 function menuTransition() {
  const dropDownContent = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
  dropDownContent.classList.add('dropdown-transition');

  setTimeout(function() {
   dropDownContent.classList.remove('dropdown-transition');
  }, 500);
 }
})();
```

```css
#nav {
 align-items: center;
 background: #1d0e96;
 display: flex;
 height: 60px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

#nav ul {
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
  height: 100%;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#nav li {
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

#nav a {
 align-items: center;
 color: #fff;
 display: flex;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a:hover {
 background: #10075d;
}

.dropdown {
 display: block;
 left: -169px;
 overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 width: 100vw;
}

.dropdown-content {
 background: #ddd;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  pointer-events: none;
 transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
 transition: transform 0s;
}

.dropdown-transition {
 transition: transform .5s;
}

.dropdown-open .dropdown-content {
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
 <nav id="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
   <li class="parent-nav">
    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
     <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet dictum leo. Pellentesque pulvinar consectetur ante ac finibus. Suspendisse dictum orci nec condimentum luctus. Sed semper lectus a quam placerat vestibulum. Vestibulum luctus sem at tincidunt vehicula. Mauris nec sapien aliquam, maximus arcu ac, condimentum diam. Cras mattis dui quis posuere bibendum. Cras venenatis semper purus, nec suscipit nulla placerat in. Fusce tincidunt pretium vulputate. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris eu libero iaculis, facilisis ex cursus, mollis ipsum. Suspendisse nec libero accumsan, gravida nibh sed, blandit nibh. Suspendisse nec turpis imperdiet, vehicula justo nec, auctor mi.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

Here's my JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/fsv75dkh/

Comment: Under `.dropdown-content` change to `pointer-events:all` in your css and you'll get your behavior you want, but I don't really understand why any of the javascript bloat is necessary anyway, could make this thing in just pure css without the listeners, queryselector's etc....

Comment: Thanks. I know what you're talking about with the bloat. I was just digging around in Google's code and stylesheet and trying and replicate how they did it.

Comment: There is, however, the issue with transition:transform that flickers the animation when loading the page. I guess that's why JS is used to briefly add in that CSS property when firing the event.

Comment: Well, I guess it does not do that in this instance. I wiped out all the JS and added this into my CSS, along with your minor pointer-event suggestion: 
.parent-nav:hover .dropdown-content {
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

Answer (score 0):

I added **pointer-events: all** to the **.dropdown-content** element, then added in the following to the CSS:

```
.parent-nav:hover .dropdown-content {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

With that, I no longer need any of the JavaScript.